# Highchart highstock startOnTick Error

Tags: highcharts

When startOnTick is set to false in highstock browser freezes.

The only think I want to do is to set exactly the max and the min of

the chart without rounding, I've found that endOnTick and startOnTick are the way to go

Here's a working code

```
series.yAxis.update({
    min: my_min_value,      
    max: my_max_value,  
    tickInterval: (my_max_value-my_min_value)/10,
    showLastLabel: true,
    showFirstLabel: true
    endOnTick: false,
    //startOnTick: false // CAUSES BROWSER crash
};
```

If I uncomment the startOnTick line, the browser start using 100%cpu and I have to kill it.

I've found that the function **getMinorTickPositions** in highstock.js

gets wrong values for pos in this line and never exits the for

**for (pos = axis.min + (tickPositions[0] - axis.min) % minorTickInterval; pos <= 
axis.max; pos += minorTickInterval)**

Answer (score 1):

You need choose which yAxis should be updated by index and update as global object not in the series.

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false
        });
```

StartOnTick works only in highcharts, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/kLN55/3/